# Pseudocode to Java -- Hoare's partition algorithm -- What's wrong here?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement this:

[image]

In pseudo things start with 1. In my code things start with 0. Other than that there is no difference.

I'm getting incorrect result:

```
arr content:
11  2   4   1   7   5   
New arr content:
1   2   4   7   11  5
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void hQuickSort(int[] A, int p, int r) {

    if (p < r) {

        int q = hPartition(A, p, r);

        hQuickSort(A, p, q);
        hQuickSort(A, q + 1, r);
    }

}

public static int hPartition(int[] A, int p, int r) {
    int pivot = A[p];
    int i = p;
    int j = r;
    int temp;

    while (true) {
        while (A[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }

        while (A[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        if (i < j) {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
        } else {
            return j;
        }
    }

}
```

invoke with an array of 6 elements:

```
    hQuickSort(arr, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Hint: "while" and "until" have opposite meanings.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks! Now I'm getting partially incorrect results. Updated my question. Any ideas?

Comment: My bad, it is working properly! But i have no idea why!!

Comment: There is another bug in this implementation: if A[i] and A[j] are both equal to the pivot, then you have an infinite loop.